# What factors will make a decision tree superior to a logistics regression model, taking into account the following?

Tags: regression, logistic, cart

Assume that the lift chart indicates that the decision tree is inferior, the C statistic is superior for the logistics regression also.

What other factors will make a decision tree better, even in lieu of the above? Both the decision tree and logistics regression have a similar misclassification statistic.

Comment: Welcome to cross validated,  you've asked: `What other factors will make a decision tree better,` in order to answer that question in a rigorous way you need a loss function to define what you mean by 'better'. Unless you want to use human judgment in which case there may not be more to say here from a statistical perspective.

Comment: By better, I mean making the decision tree more preferred. The question is related to predicting heart disease risk. @LucasRoberts hope this helps

Comment: As per @LucasRoberts you need a loss function to determine what you mean by *preferred* and *better*

Comment: That comment doesn't really answer the question. Do you mean better sensitivity, specificity, accuracy, or something else? Do you mean better explanation or prediction?

Comment: @PeterFlom-ReinstateMonica fair point, the OP doesn't necessarily need a loss function ***per se*** but does need a function of some form to quantify what 'better' means.